# Alfresco using opencmis apache chemistry to create a link to a Folder

Tags: alfresco, opencmis

Hi guys i am doing alfresco using **opencmis apache chemistry**.
I have done many services such as creating folder,subfolder,uploading,downloading with version updates.
Now i am trying to **generate link of folder/document whatever the link is in 
dashboard of alfresco**.
Somebody is there who can help me to genrate the link using `openCmis`(`java`)??
Thanks in advance

```html
public  String dowloadingDocument(String docuementID){
   Session cmisSession=new CreateSession().getSession();
   Document document=(Document) cmisSession.getObject(docuementID);
     String link=null;
      try {
         Method loadLink = AbstractAtomPubService.class.getDeclaredMethod("loadLink", 

             new Class[] { String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class });

  try {
   
   link=(String) loadLink.invoke(cmisSession.getBinding().getObjectService(),cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getId(),document.getId(),AtomPubParser.LINK_REL_CONTENT,null);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SecurityException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
      return link;
      
}
```

Comment: Do you need the link for directly downloading the file or for displaying the file in the the browser inside share UI?

Comment: what do you mean with link I've done the same thing with `J2EE` and i have a path to get my `File` or `Folder` from my app is this what you want ???

Comment: hi Younes thanks for respond.I want generate the link for my folder,document using java code(open cmis).Can u help me??

Comment: Hi yagami i want generate the link of a specific folder, but not by using simply path.I am posting the demo for creating download link for document.Same like i want for folder.Here if i pass folder id link is coming null.I am posting the code in my question

Comment: just an additionnel question what is the purpose of this link, is it to download a document ???

Comment: Just an information when you target someone @MdNoorshid to notifie this person

Comment: @YagamiLight Yes yagami it is for download the link,please same like i want generate the link for folder.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet gives you a download link for the document:

```
Document document= (Document)cmisSession.getObject(docuementID);
String link = document.getContentUrl();
```

This is not same link you'll find the Alfresco dashboard, but it also lets the user download the document. Please note, that depending on the authentication setup the user has to authenticate again before the download starts.

Comment: Hi Florian thanks for your response.But this is not the exactly solution of my requirement.I want generate link for the Folder.How this can possible?? Thanks again for your response!!

Comment: There are no links for folder in CMIS. What should they return? You can compile a Browser Binding link for a folder. It would return a JSON response with all the children of the folder. But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi Florian Muller it is quiet possible.Please once check this link https://forums.alfresco.com/comment/9450 . But they have done through webservice and i want do using opencmis.

Comment: You can get the property "alfcmis:nodeRef" and build whatever URL you need with it. But this is outside CMIS and Alfreco specific.

Comment: Florian Can you post code here how to build the url using cmis.Because only right now i have started learning alfresco .It will be better for me if you post exactly the same code whatever i have given you the link but using cmis.Thanks in advance buddy!!